# What was the first desktop computer with fully-functional input and output?

Tags: history

What was the first desktop computing system that satisfied the following features:

- It fully fit on desktop
- It included the full alpha-numeric keyboard
- It included a full text display, terminal or printer
- Was capable of long-term memory, like a disk drive or magnetic tape

For reference, let's take Soviet Elektronika-60 from 1978, which was a PDP-11 16-bit clone but was fitting in a normal desktop case. It needed a text terminal, but the whole system fit on a desktop quite well. But since the USSR lagged behind, I think, the West had earlier designs that satisfy the definition.

Can one say that the first desktop computer was a Datapoint 2200 from 1970? Were there custom applications for it, games, programming languages?

[image]

Datapoint 2200 was quite compact and included two tape drives in the single case. It also included up to 16K memory.

Given these characteristics, I wonder whether there were less compact and integrated devices before, but with similar capabilities, for instance, with discrete terminal, keyboard and storage?

Comment: The last paragraph renders that question inappropriate as it no longer asks for the titular desktop computer.

Comment: @Raffzahn I am asking for systems fitting  on a desktop exclusively.

Comment: As soon as a terminal is needed anything goes. One can place any 1970s mini on a table and a terminal beside.

Comment: @Raffzahn hardly they would fit well. Also, since DataPoint 2200 was released in 1970/1971, later computers definitely will not win even if counted.

Comment: What is the purpose of a computer without I/O devices?  Nothing.

Comment: It all depends on the size of the desktop. BTW, many users of modern computers doesn't have the computer in the desktop, only the input/output devices.

Comment: "What was the first..." questions are highly subjective. _You_ think that a computer is not "fully functional" if it does not have a "full" alpha-numeric keyboard. Somebody else might disagree with you about whether or not a certain keyboard is "full." Another person might argue that a computer could be "fully functional" even with no alphabetic characters at all. I once had a copy\* of a list that somebody made of computers that one author or another had called "the world's first computer." There were more than thirty different machines on the list. \[\*Lost it! \]

Comment: @SolomonSlow Are you maybe thinking of Doug Salot's _["What was the first personal computer"](http://www.blinkenlights.com/pc.shtml)_ Quiz?

Comment: If by "full text display" you mean a CRT with multiple rows and columns of text, I'd suggest the Sphere 1 which came out in October 1975. It had a 6800 CPU, CRT, keyboard with numeric keypad all in one unit. Floppy drives were available. There is a Wikipedia article about it.

Comment: @TimLocke thanks for the link. But DataPoint 2200 also had a multi-line display (with less resolution though).

Comment: Can you say why 'desktop' comes into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEC GT40 - 1972**
[image]

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_GT40

What was the first desktop computing system that satisfied the following features:

It fully fits on a desktop

- Refer to Wikipedia photo.

It included the full alpha-numeric keyboard

- Refer LK40 keyboard on top of system in Wikipedia photo.

It included a full text display, terminal or printer

- Refer to the integrated video display that was capable of graphics and text in Wikipedia photo. Also included a light pen

Was capable of long-term memory, like a disk drive or magnetic tape

- Mass storage was an option.

GT40 Lunar lander game.
Refer to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4lPE5Nytfc

A very late edit...
The PDP-8 was initially sold in a configuration for the desktop. They termed it the tabletop model. You could attach a CRT display and a light pen and you basically have the GT40 configuration on a desktop capable of running applications, games and languages.It would probably have required a papertape reader or DECTape.

A much later edit:.
Deleted reference to core memory and added mass storage. The booklet '''Ninteen fifty-severn to the present''', published by DEC, GT40 entry, Page 31 included:
"... the GT40 incorporated an 11/10 minicomputer, making the system expandable with mass storage as well as with other I/O options."
http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/_Books/DEC_1957_To_The_Present_1978.pdf

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149393/discussion-on-answer-by-pdp11-what-was-the-first-desktop-computer-with-fully-fun); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: GT40 seems an odd choice, since it's a PDP-11/10 (in a standard 11/10 box) with extra stuff.  An 11/10 with a VT05 would presumably have been available a few months before the GT40.  Also, while I understand that core is non-volatile, 'core for long-term storage' is a stretch.

Comment: See chat for discussion regarding data storage options.

Comment: @another-dave I wonder whether GT 40 was the first PDP-11/10 shipped in its own cabinet (case) instead of being intended to be mounted into a rack.

Comment: PDP-8/e from 1970 or PDP-8/s from 1966 might be even a better candidate. Can you identify boxes in this picture (at least the blue box seems to be completely unrelated): https://www.reddit.com/r/retrobattlestations/comments/e91klp/a_long_time_in_the_making_my_dec_pdp8e_lab8e/ ?

Comment: The blue boxes are microcomputers, nothing to do with the -8.  The green-hued PDP-8/E is part of a [LAB-8/E](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp8/lab8e/DEC-LB-HRZA_D_LAB8E_Users_Handbook_Nov71.pdf), which is apparently intended to be rack-mounted.  And the RX01 floppy drive is a rack unit.  Nevertheless, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-8/e) says the 8/E was available as a table-top system.

Answer (score 40):

### TL;DR: It's the [Olivetti P6060](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_P6060), introduced in April of 1975.

IMHO that's the first machine ticking all boxes while operating mostly like we would expect it from today's PoV

---

### Definition

Desktop computer is a bit of a vague definition, even today as one may have his desktop box mounted beside a desk. Likewise including terminal based systems, as that would enable any pile of tech that fits on top of a desk as 'desktop'(*1). The mentioned [Electronika 60](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektronika_60) being one of them, as it's a rack mount mini (*2), not a desktop.

Also, anyone remember all those desk-mounted S100 boxes (*3). Plus all those machines that could be ordered with a desk dedicated to hold those components (*4).

Bottom line, the early computer world was way more colourful than a single term can distinguish. For a reasonable answer two additional restrictions may be helpful:

- The machine must fit at whole on top of a desk
- It must be intended to be placed that way
- Monitor and Keyboard are the only components that may be discrete and movable

### The Candidates

With that we can see several distinct answers. All of the following systems have been called 'first desktop' and/or 'first personal computer' at some point:

#### Calculator Like Computers

Here foremost the **1965 [Olivetti P101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programma_101)**, eventually the [first desktop computer](https://www.fondazioneadrianolivetti.it/en/p101-cecam/). It included all components (keyboard, printer, magnetic card storage), although text capabilities as well as RAM were rather limited.

[image]

(Taken from [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_Programma_101#/media/File:Olivetti_Programma_101_-_Museo_scienza_e_tecnologia_Milano.jpg))

The follow up **1967 [P203](https://www.technikum29.de/de/rechnertechnik/kommerzielle.php#olivetti-p203)** included an Editor 4ST typewriter-terminal, making it its own desk. Text manipulation was still rather limited. Usage was more about integrating calculatory results when needed.

[image]

(Taken from [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_P203#/media/File:Olivetti_Programma_203.jpg))

#### Desktop But Not Really

If mini computers are to be included (*5), then DEC's **1965 [PDP-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-8)** could make an interesting contender as it was clearly designed to be put on a table or sideboard (*6):

[image: PDP-8]

([Picture](http://computermuseum.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/dev/pdp8/pdp8.html) taken from the fine *Computermuseum der Stuttgarter Informatik*)

The size of the partially shown TTY does tell a story how 'practical' putting that beast on your desktop would have been. Also, it's only the CPU, so any storage also had to be placed somewhere.

#### Terminals That Could Be Computers

This is where the mentioned **1970 [Datapoint 2200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datapoint_2200)** and others, like the **1971 Cogar 4** (*7), fit. Those systems were all in one desktop units featuring some long term storage, a full card punch compatible keyboard and a CRT of limited size. Their purpose wasn't to act as stand alone desktop systems but replace [Remote Job Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_job_entry) (RJE *8) stations at lower price while offering more flexibility.

Use as stand alone systems only developed over time.

While third party software was available, it was at first mostly applications and mostly written in assembly, although both companies soon offered a COBOL alike development systems. The smallest possible configuration to run any development was 4 KiB and cassettes using CTOS and Databus, although only a cut down version. Any usable development environment would need at least 8 KiB to run DOS and an external (19" rack sized) 2,5 MiB Diabolo Disk system. In reality anyone developing would need the full 16 KiB of a 2200 Version 2

[image: Datapoint with 2.5 MiB Disk Drive]

Such a development setup would end up past 25,000 USD - or the equivalent of 14 1972 model VW cars.

The Cogar 4 might be in addition noteworthy as its character set was fully ram based and redefinable, allowing bitmap graphics as well, a feature CTC only provided with the later 5500 model.

#### Almost There

While HP still marketed **1972 [HP 9830A](https://www.hpmuseum.org/hp9830.htm)** as 'calculator', they did integrate a full keyboard, a 32 character display and a cassette unit with CPU and 4 KiB of RAM. in a single desktop case. With the optional full size HP 9866 thermal printer the hardware setup might fit the required definition.

[image]

(Taken from [Computermuseum der Stuttgarter Informatik](http://computermuseum.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/dev/hp9830/))

The picture shows nicely how unreal that tower get with disk drive and printer added.

Software wise it was all to be programmed in BASIC, though, a version 'optimized' for calculatory application. To handle text an optional ROM called 'String Variables' (HP 11274) had to be installed. It added string variables and functions to handle text to the build in BASIC. Further ROMS (Advanced Programming 1&2) added further basic functionality, like keyboard operation as with a typewriter and more string/database functions.

The late **1974 [MCM/70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCM/70)** was not only the second micro processor (8008) based computer to be marketed (*9), but also the first desktop unit. It featured a single line display, up to two cassette drives and a typewriter style keyboard. Its [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) environment was quite advanced for its time, but not exactly what one would use for text processing. Not that it wouldn't work (ignoring limited memory for a moment), it was just ... unusual.

#### (The Inbetweens)

The **1973 [Wang 2200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_2200)s** are a remarkable intermediate. While [early 2200](https://www.wang2200.org/systems.html#SYS2200WCS) still had a CPU box mounted in/under a table their terminal did also contain its mass storage cassette drive.

#### All-In-One and All-On-Top

The **1975 [Olivetti P6060](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_P6060)** might eventually be the first desktop computer from today's point of view. It included a full keyboard, an LED display (CRT optional) and a full width printer together with the computer in a quite stylish 1970s (*10) case.

[image]

*([Picture](http://www.z80ne.com/p6060/restauro/31.jpg) taken from this very detailed [dissection of a P6060](http://www.z80ne.com/p6060/restauro/restauro.asp))*

Most notable here is the very early use of floppy drives for data storage.

#### The Rest is History

In September **1975**, Half a year after the P6060 IBM introduced the **[IBM 5100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_5100)** desktop (*11). It featured a small CRT, a typewriter keyboard and a [QIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-inch_cartridge) tape drive (*12). APL and BASIC version were available. It wasn't until the **1978 [5110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_5110)** that a (fridge sized) floppy drive was added.

[image: IBM 5100]

(Taken from [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_5100#/media/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:IBM_5100_-_MfK_Bern.jpg))

By March **1976** Wang as well managed to fit the CPU into the terminal case, creating their first all in one desktop system, the **[2200 PCS](https://www.wang2200.org/systems.html#SYS2200PCS)**.

1976 will also be the year that all-in-one desktop micros like TRS-80 or PET became the prototypical desktop units.

---

*1 - Anyone remember [North Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Star_Horizon) systems? With their wooden top cover they were marketed to fit 1970s office desks, but I've never seen one placed that way. Usually below or in a separate shelf.

*2 - By 1978 western rack mount systems of similar size could already have included mass storage as well as graphics output, marginally qualifying as desktop ... except, at that time real desktop were already standard devices.

*3 - [Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Graphic) offered mounting sets for their boxes so they could be hung below the table or at the side (like a tower).

*4 - Wang (and others) h[ad nice tables](https://i0.wp.com/www.curbsideclassic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/3151.jpeg) holding the CPU in some cabinet while the board had a hole to lower the terminal part, so the keyboard comes out levelled.

*5 - That is beside gluing rubber feet under an otherwise rack mount box to stay put on a table.

*6 - Though, more serious I'd say a pedestal (or sideboard) is rather what they had in mind for their new beauty :)

*7 - Or Singer 1500 or ICL 1500 as Cogar's company was the same year bought by Singer Business Machines just to be sold five years later to ICL. While Cogar developed it as stand allone system, it was as well associated  with the remarkable [System Ten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singer_System_Ten).

*8 - RJE is in some way the first kind of terminal application as it allowed to locate all user interaction away from the computer by adding limited local processing capability. No wonder that the cross over between RJE and early terminals produced the first Desktop-PC like devices :))

*9 - The first would be the French [Micral-N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micral).

*10 - European Stylish that is, the US design was still stuck in pre-war round forms and fake wood.

*11 - Well, they called it IBM 5100 *Portable* Computer - which its 25 kg may only be considered when compared with their mainframes :))

*12 - Which gave it an enormous 20 MiB of Storage - slow but huge.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much of a point to the original question, but why would you say the P6060 qualifies and the HP9830 - which came out in 1974 - doesn't, especially in a setup like this? http://computermuseum.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/dev/hp9830/

Comment: @MichaelGraf 1974? Maybe Klemens Krause needs to check up again. the 98xx series was introduced all in 1972 (9830 as 9800 Model 30). And yes, many may qualify. That's why I not just presented the P6060, but a gradual list of machines. Main point is, as written, that the 9830 in its out-of-the-box configuration does not really qualify for text handling. Part due inabilities of the OS (keyboard), BASIC (string handling) and display (no CRT or full printer as required by the question). All of that can be overcome by adding Hardware as described in its section. The P6060 had all of that right away

Comment: I am asking for systems fitting on a desktop, not named "desktop computer". Elektronika-60 fits on a desktop well.

Comment: "Monitor and Keyboard are the only components that may be discrete and movable" - not necessarily. For instance, DVK had two cases under the monotor: the computer itself and the terminal electronics. But it definitely fits the definition: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Soviet_computer_DVK-2.JPG

Comment: @Anixx Can be put is not the same as intended to be put. Any computer can be put on a desktop. But that doesn't make it a desktop computer. To earn the designation it needs to be build for that purpose, which an Electronica-60 is not. I would suggest to get a bit more familiar with computer terminology as well as history before arguing about basic terms.

Comment: I could not find any info about Cogar 4.

Comment: @Anixx You may want to look for 'Singer 1500' or 'ICL 1500' instead as mentioned in footnote *5. The company got sold short after the terminal was introduced to Singer and later ICL, so it's more known under the later names.

Comment: Elektronika-60 definitely was designed to be put on desktop. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/ArmSCII_02%2C_First_Armenian_Computer_-_Electronika_60.jpg

Comment: Well, good compilation. I only do not see in what Olivetti P6060 is better than DataPoint 2200

Comment: @Anixx Well, the Datapoint could not be truly operated on its own. It was intended as adaptable data station. It could load and run programs, but only of rather limited size, likewise data was quite restricted. Development had to happen on larger systems. To be used on its own for development it needed to be greatly expanded (memory and external drives). It wasn't until the mid 1970s that later versions became self supporting systems. The P6060 in turn is intended as self sufficient computer for all usage including development.

Comment: @Raffzahn it had memory of 16 KB, which is the size of the memory on the Soviet BK-0010 home computer, which remained in use deep into the 1990s and had BASIC, Turbo Assembler, Focal, Pascal, C, Forth, Fortran, Prolog and other compilers and interpreters.

Comment: Yes I fondly remember North Star - the first computer I programmed to do data acquisition, followed shortly by a Terak.

Comment: Why is it that every time an "answer" just drives the whole topic into the ground, it's always signed by this "Raffzahn?" +1 if only just for that beautiful photo of a Straight 8 sitting on a desk top.

Comment: @Anixx 16 KiB was **maximum** RAM expansion. By default it had only 2 KiB of RAM. Expanding it to 16 KiB was incredible expensive. It tripled the price from $5000 to $14000. That's the same as 7 factory new VW cars in 1970. The BK0010 had 16/32 KiB _plus_ 32 KiB ROM with OS and language tools. The 2200 had no language in ROM. Everything had to be loaded into RAM. It's not useful to have OS, Assembler and screen memory in just 2 KiB - not to mention any more complex language. And especially no room for source text. it was barely good to exit a few lines of text and store them right away on tape

Comment: @SolomonSlow Come to [Stuttgart](https://www.f05.uni-stuttgart.de/informatik/fachbereich/computermuseum) and touch it. Plus a lot of [other nice stuff](http://computermuseum.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/cm003.html). I deeply envy their working(!) [LGP-30](https://www.f05.uni-stuttgart.de/informatik/fachbereich/computermuseum/aktuelles/LGP-30/).

Comment: @MichaelGraf Looking thru the Stuttgart pages it seems as the dates given are about their specimen, not the system in general, so 1974 would be the time the Uni acquired a 9830, which does sound right and clears the confusion.

Comment: @Anixx Correction, I just looked up my manuals, the original Datapoint 2200 came with 2 KiB of RAM and could be ordered with an extension of 2,4 or 6 KiB for a maximum total of 8 KiB RAM. It wasn't until the 1973 Version II that it could be expanded  from 2 KiB to a maximum of 16 KiB.  The version II was a greatly enhanced machien with different structure (about 50 times faster)

Comment: I was wondering whether the LGP-30 (1956) was a possible contender, or an accounting machine such as the TC500 https://www.retrocomp.si/cms/2018/04/05/burroughs-tc-500/ In any event, I think we can all agree that something that doesn't have space for the operator's knees is excluded, but it's fair to ask whether "is a desk" rather than "can be put on a desk" is another useful distinction.

Comment: Everything can be put on a desk, given a sufficiently large desk and a forklift.

Comment: @Raffzahn this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKk-RU9u6-4 says version II of DP2200 with 16 KB by default came in spring 1972. In BK-0010 the RAM was 16 KB, not 32.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd thanks for interesting references! TC500 is describes in the manual as "desk type computer".

Comment: @Anixx It had a small serial processor not entirely unlike the LGP-30, small disc memory (to circumvent the LGP-30's patented use of a drum), and a golfball printer controlled by steel tapes (to circumvent IBM's patented use of steel wires). Various banks started deploying them in the very late 60s, which means in practice that if this form factor is acceptable to the question then the LGP-30 has about a decade's precedence.

Comment: @Anixx You may want to watch that video again, it does not state anything about what the default RAM size was. likewise no information about delivery. For serious information you may want to read [Lamont Woods's book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16214216-datapoint), not some random Youtube video. Regarding the BK, it was a 16 bit machine, thus needing 16 RAM chips making it either 32 Ki (4116) or 128 Ki (4164). Just count the chips oft [this picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bk0010-01-systemboard.jpg) on [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/БК_(семейство_компьютеров)).

Comment: @Raffzahn BK-0010 without extension cards had 16 KB RAM. I had this machine and I know this. The other chips seemingly were used for screen memory. When we speak about DataPoint 2200 we also do not count screen memory.

Comment: @Anixx Sorry, but you might have to refresh your memory. I own [BK-0010 systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbDq0.jpg) and can verify it's flat 32 KiB RAM. Due being a 16 bit CPU the chips must be used as a single group. Having16 KiB accessed by video generation doesn't change that fact that they are part of CPU memory. The 2200 in turn had no video memory in the CPU address space, but a dedicated terminal type setup for keyboard and screen using the external bus (address341). Those are two different concepts, so please do not mix them.

Comment: @Raffzahn screen memory is CPU-accessible memory in all raster graphics computers, including the modern wintel. But screen memory is not counted as RAM. Regarding 2200, I do not know how its video memory was organized. But the video memory definitely existed.

Comment: @Anixx CPU accessible is not the same as in CPU address space which again is different from graphics memory being part of main memory or not That's especially true for most PC graphics. - they are for one not part of main memory and in addition neither fully present in expansion access. Just take a look at VGA.  Last, if you do not know how video memory of a machine is organized you should better abstain from using it in as reference. Please learn the very basics before trying to argue.

Comment: @Raffzahn lol, I very well know how the video memory on BK is organized. Additionally, I wrote programs in x86 assembler that were drawing pictures by directly accessing the video memory, so basically they are organized the same on x86 and BK.

Comment: The HP9830A was the top of the 9800 line. There were also HP9810A and HP9820A. My colleagues and I certainly used the 9820A as a computer. We had quite a collection of HPL programs on magnetic cards!

Comment: The HP9845 and HP85 were used in online positioning and surveying applications which were very "computery" - Qubit Trac III. (The replacement for this was typically the 200 series which ran the Trac IV).

Comment: @Anixx Well, if you know how the BK works, why do you argue otherwise. Also, PC graphics cards are not part of main memory but mapped into - and only some of them. So again big difference. You may want to learn about the topic you're talking about - just having written some program on either machine may not tell the whole story.

Comment: @JohnDoty No doubt, they all were fine machines.

Comment: @Raffzahn what "main mamory" do you mean? Screen area is ALWAYS reflected in the processor's address space.

Comment: @Anix No, it's not. Some cards may map into CPU address space, full or partial, others don't, in any case it's not part of main memory but display external. For example to access a VGA card one has to enable mapping (3C2h), Select mapping since (3CFh via 3CEh index 06h) and finally Read/write mapping has to be set (index 04/05h). In addition it has to be taken into account that access is done using a 32 bit register (which in turn offers bitblit operation and can be used for speedy within display RAM). Bottom line: it is neither main memory nor organized as the Access makes it look.

Comment: Corrected/Expanded the entry regarding the GT40 to add mass storage option. Wish this info was added to the longer answer.

Comment: @PDP11 Not sure why you want to post info about another answer here. The GT40 falls into the same category as the Datapoint or other units which contain a CPU but fall short of the definition posted. Being able to pile additional devices onto the same desk doesn't change it.

Comment: I don't see how the GT40 fails. Physical height of the processor was less than or equal to an IBM XT PC. GT40 could connect to mass storage devices (I've removed the reference to the non-volatile Core memory). The TRS 80 Model 1 had the disk drive in an expansion box. Same with the Microbee which had external drives in a box. An IBM PC required an external CRT monitor which could be as large as the GT40. Day 1 the GT40 could play games, run programs in high level language, edit files, etc. It meets all the requirements. I used to maintain the processors with 8" floppy disks.

Comment: Requirement of the question.
    It fully fit on desktop
    It included the full alpha-numeric keyboard
    It included a full text display, terminal or printer
    Was capable of long-term memory, like a disk drive or magnetic tape

Comment: Its is historic machine i.e. the first example. The question did not require a Personal Computer to contain the mass storage inside the case as there were plenty of designs where the cassette drives and floppy disks where external to the processor case. The  Wikipedia definition of a personal computer does not require the mass storage in the CPU case. The question explicitly states "Given these characteristics, I wonder whether there were less compact and integrated devices before, but with similar capabilities, for instance, with discrete terminal, keyboard and storage?" GT40 satisfies.

Comment: Your answer is really great. If I was in StackExchange looking for an answer to this exact same question then you have provided a great survey but incomplete. I wouldn't want to dive in and edit your answer against your wishes, nor do a wholesale cut and paste of your material into my question, to write my own conclusion and basically claim it was my work. That is why I'm suggesting you include the GT40 in your answer.

Comment: @PDP11 The question is about a desktop type computer, not building a system on top of a desk from arbitrary components - otherwise _any_ computer would qualify, even a mainframe needing Putins table to make it work :)) I believe answers should not rest in a  fan attitude toward certain manufacturers but deliver reasonable content.

Comment: I guess there is not going to be an agreement on what constitutes the design limits of the packaging of a desktop computer. The person who asked the question has to decide what are the design limits that satisfies their question.

This issue is not going to be resolved here as it is just down to personal opinions. This thread would be more appropriately held as a Chat topic. It will return to the person who posed the question as to what they meant by a desktop computer.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.cedmagic.com/history/dec-pdp-8.html

It's a real stretch to call this a desktop computer,  but that claim was made.  It's one model of the DEC PDP-8 computer, from the 1960s.  I would never put this thing on my desk.

But it is fair to say that DEC (Digital Equipement Corporation) introduced the minicomputer to the world, and that the PDP-8 was the earliest entry.  The PDP-11 dominated the minicomputer industry for almost a decade.

Once you have grasped the mnicomputer concept,  the next obvious step is the microcomputer, and the microcomputer belongs on the desktop.  This was obvious to everyone, except DEC.  DEC was slow in entering the microcomputer derby,  and its entries didn't look all that attractive to consumers,  either for the office or the home.  That's a long, complicated story, and it's central to the decline and fall of DEC.

At one time, DEC was the number two computer vendor in the world, after IBM.  Fifteen years later, only the old-timers remembered DEC.

If you want to see other early desktop computers from DEC,  look up the DECmate II,  the Rainbow 100, and the Pro-350.  They reentered the desktop market later on with the VAXmate and a few other entries.  But they were never able to gain the marketshare needed to make it profitable.

BTW,  the first computer I owned ws a DEC Rainbow, purchased through the employee program.

Comment: The photos show that it did not have a text keyboard and display: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FRW24tEXIAImfxJ?format=jpg&name=small

Comment: @Anixx: Your question allows using a separate terminal on the same desk, which the PDP-8 certainly supported.

Comment: Indeed, PDP-8 is a contender, although the design of the 1960s is so diffrerent that it is difficult to relate it to the design of 1970s and 1980s.

Comment: @Anixx FWIW modern desktop PCs don't have keyboard or display unless you don't consider modern PCs to be desktops (which is fair because most people have them on the floor)

Comment: @slebetman modern PCs with keyboard and monotor fit on a sesktop well. Also, there are laptops, etc.

Comment: @Anixx Well, a PDP-8 monitor and keyboard would also fit on a desktop well

Comment: @slebetman the one shipped with it was standing on the floor.

Answer (score 3):

The IEEE proclaimed the Datapoint 2200 the first:
[image: The IEEE awarded the Datapoint 2200 this award, in 2022, proclaiming it the first desktop personal computer]

Comment: Was it introduced in 1969 though?

Comment: Well, I agree that this was probably the first. Although, I think, one could compose a desktop system from DEC components earlier, for instance, based on PDP-8/S.

Comment: The first glass terminal compatible with PDP-8 though was DataPoint 3300.

Answer (score 0):

Honorable mention -- The Altair 8800. This is the computer that moved Bill Gates to drop out of Harvard, in order to avoid being too late to start a company.  The computer was featured ina magazine of January 1975,  and when Paul Allen showed it to Bill Gates, he decided that the time to start offering software for microcomputers had arrived.

https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/history-of-computers,4518-22.html

Comment: It had no keyboard or display. That's why keyboard and display are explicitely mentioned in the question.